# After I move files out of the recycle bin, why are they relabeled with weird filenames like $RLVX8SW.tar?

Tags: windows-7

It happens to all files that I try to move out of the recycle bin.

Comment: How exactly do you move them out of the Recycle Bin (drag, Restore, ...)?  Which drive is the recycled file on (look at the Original Location column)?  Give us an example of one of the original file names.

Comment: Can't repro this on about 5 different machines running Windows 7... Tell us what's different about your setup from a stock configuration.

Comment: Oh yeah - TeraCopy. I just found that out

Answer (score 1):

It seems you must restore/undelete them through the system menus because the original names and locations are stored in a database. Dragging them out manually appears to be losing that information.

Comment: Interesting - you're right. I usually use TeraMove

Comment: ^Teracopy - sorry